# CS50 Python pset3

Tags: python, cs50

I'm trying to solve problem outdated where I have to convert "american dates (MM,DD,YYY)" to ISO8601 (YYYY,MM,DD).
This is my code:

```
def main():
    Months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
    ]


    while True:
        Date = input("Please insert a Date: ").strip().title().replace(",", "").replace(" ", "/").split("/")
        try:
            Month = Date[0]
            Day = Date[1]
            Year = Date[2]

            if Month in Months:
                Month = Months.index(Month)+1


            if Day.isalpha() == True:
                pass
            elif int(Day) > 31 or int(Month) > 12:
                pass
            else:
                print(f"{Year}-{int(Month):02}-{int(Day):02}")
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass
main()
```

There are some constraints, I've solved 9 but there are 2 I consider that should be handled by the program
but as they are expected to fail and re-prompt the user I got stuck.
these are the inputs that should fail:

```
October/9/1701
September 8 1636
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: `input("Please insert a Date: ").strip().title().replace(",", " ").replace("/", " ").split(" ")` would produce the expected results.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `datetime` module to format and parse dates?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is not a homework help site per se, it's a Q&A site, and questions need to be specific. What are you stuck on exactly? Are you looking for this? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341). If not, please [edit] and provide expected output and actual output (see [mre]), and write a specific title (see [ask]). If you want more tips, check out [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

Even though they are handled by the program, they are expected to fail and reprompt at per the spec:

> If the user’s input is not a valid date in either format [formatted like `9/8/1636` or `September 8, 1636`], prompt the user again.

The program needs to verify the input is in one of the specified input formats *before* it slices and dices into the output format. Have the `while` loop detect proper input, and then do the  formatting. Psuedo-something like:

```
while True:
    input(adate)
    if date is mm/dd/yy:
       do something
    else if date is Month day, year:
       do something else
    else:
       reprompt

produce the output
```